# Wildcard SSL certificate does not work with naked domain

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I have deployed a wildcard certificate (Comodo PlatinumSSL) for `*.example.com` on Apache/Ubuntu 14.04. Everything works if the client visits `https://www.example.com` but `https://example.com` throws up this in Firefox:

```
example.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is only valid for *.example.com 
(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

Extracts from the vhost file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/localcerts/example_com.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example_com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/example_com_interm.cer
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

How do I get both `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com` to work without warnings?

Comment: Wildcard certs don't work that way.

Comment: Due to problem with wildcard support on mobile platforms, we scrapped them moved to multidomain certs.  

With Multi-domain (as with wildcards) you lose the "extra" coverage of the base domain and one additional record (typically 'www') you get with most single domain certificates.

Comment: So in general...

Comment: Single Domain Cert-  Covers domain and 1 additional record (likely 'www'), widely supported.

Comment: Wildcard Cert - Covers any subdomain but not the bare hostname because it is not a subdomain.  Not good for legacy clients and is a problem with mobile clients which do not support SNI because inevitably you will have two services on the same ip.

Comment: Multi-domain cert: Single certificate file covering any number of hosts, even across domains.  Is not an issue for virtual hosting (thinking websites here) or SNI because the certificate is the same for all the virtual hosts on the box.

Comment: The final point is what lead us to Multi-Domain certificates.  Without appearing to advertise for sslmate, their package allows us to add, remove and edit hosts in our certificate without any charges unless we are buying one for a new host. They also provide current apache/nginx config which get A+ from SSL Labs, which is good because we are not cryptographers.

Comment: Multi Domain certs are more convenient for system administration because it allows us to quickly deploy and modify stuff across a large number of servers with only having one or two certificates. Managing single domain certificates across all these boxes was literally a nightmare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A wildcard matches a single left-most label. That is `*.example.com` matches `www.example.com` but not `example.com` or `sub.foo.example.com`. This means you either  need to get a certificate which includes `*.example.com` and `example.com` as subject alternative names or if you just need `www` and the naked domain name then you can  can get a cheaper certificate which only includes `www.example.com` and `example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

More information on certificates with and without the www domain can be found [here](http://allben.net/post/2009/02/01/SSL-Certificate-for-WWW-and-no-WWW).

This [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www) has the same subject as your question and basically states that there is no work-around, other than buying a new certificate